# Infinite number of intermediate fields between K(u,v) and K

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> $K$ is an infinite field with char $K =p >0$ and suppose $L=K(u,v)$ where $u^p, v^p\in K $and $[L:K]=p^2$. Show that there exist infinite number of distinct intermediate fields between $K$ and $ L$.

This is a homework problem.

Attempt: If we can prove $K(u+av)\not=K(u+bv)$ for $a\neq b$ with $a,b\in K$, then clearly we have infinite number of intermediate fields. Now suppose: $K(u+av)=K(u+bv)\implies (u+av) - (u+bv) \in K(u+av)\implies (a-b)v\in K(u+av)$

Don't know where to go from here. Also would appreciate if the proof is elementary and does not use Galois Theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right lines. Note that since $a \neq b$, then $a - b$ is invertible in $K(u+av)$, so $(a-b)v \in K(u + av) \implies v \in K(u + av)$. But that implies $u \in K(u + av)$ too, i.e. $K(u + av) = K(u, v)$.

Now you need to argue that this cannot happen. What is the degree of the field extension $[K(u + av):K]$?

Comment: From $K(u+av)=K(u,v)$, we get $[K(u+av):K]=p^2$. But since $(u+av)^p=u^p+a^p v^p\in K$ since $u^p, v^p, a \in K\implies (u+av)$ is a root of $x^p-(u^p+a^pv^p)=0\implies [K(u+av):K]\leq p$ which is a contradiction. Am I correct?

Comment: @Bosnia Yes :-)