# Prove that there are infinite number of intermediate fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Edit : My question has been linked with following question:[Infinite number of intermediate fields between K(u,v) and K](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257318/infinite-number-of-intermediate-fields-between-ku-v-and-k) , but there is a difference that in my question K is never assumed  to be an infinite field. So, it's not exactly a duplicate.

Consider the following question:

> Let char K = p $\neq 0 $ and assume F = K(u,v) where $u^{p} \in K$, $v^{p} \in K$ and $[F : K] = p^2 $.
> . Exhibit an infinite number of intermediate fields.

I think that there are $(p-1)^2$ choices and hence the same number of intermediate fields as after that $u^a v^b u^c$ can be written as $u^{a+c} v^b$ and $u^p ,v^p \in K$ . So, How are there infinite intermediate fields.

Comment: Why should an intermediate extension be generated by an element of the form $u^av^b$? Note that $F$ cannot be generated by a single element over $K$, so by the primitive element theorem $F/K$ has infinitely many intermediate fields.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835953/exhibit-an-infinite-number-of-intermediate-fields-of-k-f) for solution references.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The link has been broken. Also my question was linked with a question ( my question  has been marked as duplicate ) but the question with which I have been marked as duplicate  is significantly different because it assumes K to be an infinite field) .So , I request you to vote reopen this question.

Comment: The assumptions imply that $K$ is infinite since if $K$ were finite it would be perfect so $u$ and $v$ would be in $K$ so $F=K$ and $[F:K]=1$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Why if it would have been finite it would have implied that it is perfect? Can you please elaborate on that?